# Getting syntax errors while trying to compile a functiom

Tags: mysql, function, stored-functions

I am trying to compile the following function but get lots of syntax error. What errors am I committing? Am I missing something? Can we give the length of characters in the return type?

```
create function generate_invoice_number(id int) returns varchar(11)
    deterministic 
begin
    declare invoiceId varchar(11) default null;
    /**
         * Here id refers to the ID that is generated in the 
     * invoice table.
     */
    if id is not null and id > 0 
        then
            set invoiceId = concat('QUA-',lpad(id,7,'0'));
    end if;

    return invoiceId;
end;
```

**Errors:**

> Error Code : 1064     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 4   (0 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'if id is not null and id > 0              then
>                 set invoiceId = concat('QUA-',lpad(id,7,' at line 5     (0 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'end if' at line 1     (0 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'return invoiceId' at line 1   (0 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'end' at line 1    (0 ms taken)

Comment: Are you using any client, like Workbench or just typing the function creation into a terminal-mode interface to MySQL?

Comment: @FDavidov `SQLYog`

Comment: Sorry, don't know that one. The only thing that comes to my mind the the fact that, when using terminal mode, you need to wrap a procedure/function creation with a `delimiter` statement (I don't know if this is relevant with SQLYog though). Sorry I can't help you more than this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `delimiter` for this:

```
delimiter $$

create function generate_invoice_number(id int) returns varchar(11)
    deterministic 
begin
    declare invoiceId varchar(11) default null;
    /**
         * Here id refers to the ID that is generated in the 
     * invoice table.
     */
    if id is not null and id > 0 
        then
            set invoiceId = concat('QUA-',lpad(id,7,'0'));
    end if;

    return invoiceId;
end$$

delimiter ;
```